# Using Oracle SQL with ibatis, return a lot of similarly-calculated data

Tags: sql, oracle, ibatis

I have a query that returns one row with a ton of columns. The top part of my query looks something like this:

```
sum(CASE WHEN status = 'hello' THEN begin ELSE 0 END) hello_begin,
sum(CASE WHEN status = 'hello' THEN middle ELSE 0 END) hello_middle,
sum(CASE WHEN status = 'hello' THEN end ELSE 0 END) hello_end,

sum(CASE WHEN status = 'smile' THEN begin ELSE 0 END) smile_begin,
sum(CASE WHEN status = 'smile' THEN middle ELSE 0 END) smile_middle,
sum(CASE WHEN status = 'smile' THEN end ELSE 0 END) smile_end,

...
```

... I have 10 different statuses, so this is 30 columns. I can just write 30 statements. but is there a smart way to compress this so that I don't make some silly copy and paste error?

I'm doing this in iBatis and returning it to a mapping object, where I start a very tedious and non-extensible conversion to something like a map of maps. The ideal solution is to skip having to do that in Java, too.

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL with sp_executesql and pass the parameter for the status but I'd just copy the 'hello' block 9 times then use replace 9 times, replacing 'hello' with 'whatever'.

Comment: This seems like a case where you're using this copy-paste heavy route to solve a problem, when another solution might be better. If you provide what you're trying to address with this big query, someone might be able to help you with a more elegant solution.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  If you're using 11.1 or later, it looks like you're doing a pivot where you could use the `pivot` keyword rather than doing it yourself.

Comment: @SamDeHaan I guess I just need some way to pass these 30 bits of data back to what's calling it. Is there some other way than just putting one piece of data per column result?

Comment: It's a small difference but `sum(CASE WHEN status = 'hello' THEN begin ELSE 0 END)` can be shortened to `sum(CASE WHEN status = 'hello' THEN begin END)` or just `sum(decode(status,'hello',begin))`

Comment: This looks like you might be doing a pivot query?